# BeautifulSoup Split Text from Tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can find and print the tag:

```
name = soup.find("h1")
print(name)
```

gives:

```
<h1>Coriander<span>Herb / Cilantro</span></h1>
```

But how can I return the different parts separately? i.e. Isolated as 3 separate data points?

```
Coriander
Herb
Cilantro
```

When I try:

```
name = soup.find("h1 span")
print(name)
```

I get:

```
None
```

So I'm stuck already.

Answer (score 3):

One solution might be using `.get_text()` with custom separator and then `.split()`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    "<h1>Coriander<span>Herb / Cilantro</span></h1>", "html.parser"
)

data = [t.strip() for t in soup.h1.get_text(separator="/").split("/")]
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
['Coriander', 'Herb', 'Cilantro']
```

Comment: That's fantastic, and works great. But I'm confused why. So many questions... 1) I recognise .strip, but not t.strip, or how you can use it before "for t in soup", and why the get_text separator splits at the span when there is no slash. Anyway, thanks very much for the answer. Down the rabbit hole I go!